# how can i thymeleaf Comparators and Equality

Tags: thymeleaf

If the totalPageCount is greater than 11, i want to show the next button.
I gave the condition as thymeleaf expression but it does not work properly.

here is example.

ex ) totalPageCount  =7

```html
<span th:if="${11 &gt; totalPageCount}"></span>
```

--> 11 <  7 .
Because it is false, the button should not appear. but button is visible.
What can i do?

Comment: Hi Mina, aren't you actually doing 11>7?

Comment: hi hakamairi. 11>7 ? what do you mean? The condition of the above code is 11<7.

Comment: ${11 &gt; totalPageCount} - doesn't that mean 11 > totalPageCount?

Comment: yes. that mean 11 > totalPageCount.

Comment: Ok, so what's the condition you mentioned in the question then? I see 11>7 which resolves to true and will show the span element.